# Apache won't execute CGIs with Macports Perl5.8.9

Tags: perl, apache2, macports, mod-perl2

I'm trying to get perl running under on my Apache 2 macports install. I'm hoping an experienced perl geek can help me out. I've...

1. Got Apache running just dandy. Macports installed it with perl5 placeholder and perl5.8.9.
2. Installed mod_perl2.
3. Run the script to configure httpd.conf.
4. Restarted apache.
5. Written the following test script in htdocs

   ```
   #!/opt/local/bin/perl
   print "content-type: text/html \n\n";
   print 'Hello world.';
   ```

All I get is the script contents printed out to the screen. Am I missing a step? Is there some additional configuration I need to do in the .conf file?

Comment: Is `/opt/local/bin/perl` the location of the perl binary (or a symlink to one)? If not, start by fixing that.

Comment: correct. /opt/local/bin/perl is where macports installs the perl binary (i confirmed that it's there). I tried /usr/local/bin/perl just for fun and, as expected, it didn't work either.

Comment: Now I assume the path specified on the first line is absolute and not relative to htdocs or anything like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache hasn't been configured to recognize certain file types as cgi executables. Adding this line to your httpd.conf will do the trick, although there are many other ways of configuring this to achieve the same effect:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
```

You may also have to add `ExecCGI` to an options list for your domain. See [Apache Tutorial: Dynamic Content with CGI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html) for more information.

Comment: That did it. I owe your cat one cheeseburger. Thanks!